# Custom mouse hover-over strings in PyCharm

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm

In PyCharm debug mode, when I hover over a variable, a string appears w/ its contents. However oftentimes, this message is not very helpful. For example, for large numpy arrays, it displays the actual contents in string form (see image). What would be much more helpful is displaying the actual shape and dtype of the array (as in Matlab). Is there any way to define a custom function defining the hoverover text for different variable types?

Update: I opened a PyCharm Issue/Feature request for this here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-32916

[image]

Comment: Not sure - but in debug mode, you should be able to set a breakpoint and add this variable to watches to get more information about it.

Comment: @alex what do you mean by 'add this variable to watches'?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/adding-editing-and-removing-watches.html

Comment: @alex, thats a really cool feature, but not what I'm looking for. I want to be able to write custom functions to define what is printed out in the hoverbox during mouseover for distinct class types. (Currently I believe it is just str(var)).